# Hovering <a> won't show the dropdown

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu, and I want it to show when I hover the text, but it's not working:

This is showing the submenus:

```
nav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block; visibility: visible;
}
```

This si not showing the submenus:

```
nav ul li a:hover ul{
 display: block; visibility: visible;
}
```

How can I make the second code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this selector:

```
ul li a:hover + ul
```

what the `+` does is affecting the **ul** right after the **a** tag.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjff51zq/)